# Multiselect enable option does not work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, multi-select

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fruits').multiselect({
    name: 'fruits',
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'fruits'
  });
  $('#fruits').multiselect('disable');

  $("#changeStatuss").click(function() {
    $("#fruits").multiselect('enable');

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="filter-text">FRUITS</p>
  <select name="fruits" multiple id="fruits">
    <option value="mango">mango</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="changeStatuss" value="try me" />
```

When we run the disable option it works fine, the dropdown gets disabled, but enable option on any event trigger is not happening.
I tried other posts with the same problem but still no use.
I also tried refreshing the plugin after the enable option but again no use.

Comment: Which plug-in are you using? `multiselect` is not a part of jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('#fruits option').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me , Here is example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#fruits').multiselect({
    name: 'fruits',
    columns: 1,
    placeholder: 'fruits'
  });
  $('#fruits').multiselect('disable');

  $("#changeStatuss").click(function() {
    $("#fruits").multiselect('enable');

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="filter-text">FRUITS</p>
  <select name="fruits" id="fruits" multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="mango">mango</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="changeStatuss" value="try me" />
```